# Any shortcut or quick way to switch to views in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

Usually, I will want to display the code usage like class hierarchy and etc. And it will override the Run view. But afterwards, I want to get back to Run view to check logs. Is there any quick way to do that ? Now I have to close class hierarchy view and then open Run view which is time consuming

Answer (score 0):

Most toolwindows in IntelliJ IDEA have shortcuts that can be used for activating them. You can see the shortcuts if you open the View | Tool Windows submenu of the main menu.

The default shortcut for the Run toolwindow is Alt-4 in the default keymap or Cmd-4 in the Mac OS X 10.5+ keymap.